# removeEventListener for DOM event in helper has no effect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, architecture

I am building a simple Slider component. When a user clicks on the thumb he should be able to start dragging the thumb along the track. So at that point I am registering a mousemove event handler in my helper class:

```
startSliderDrag : function(component)
{
    console.log("register");
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onSliderMouseMove.bind(this));
},
```

So far everything is working, but when I try to unregister the handler again (as a test case after invoking the first mouse move)

```
onSliderMouseMove : function(event)
{
    console.log("mousemove");
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onSliderMouseMove);
}
```

this has no effect and the handler is called forever. What am I doing wrong? Is there another option in the framework itself to react on mouse move?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Doug who pointed me to the right direction, this works:

```
startSliderDrag : function(component)
{
    var self = this;
    var mouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
        console.log("move");
        self.anotherFunctionFromHelper(component);
    };

    var mouseUpHandler = function(event) {
        console.log("up");
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
},
```

With that approach I keep the reference to the component and have access to the mouseEvent and can remove the listeners.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with a similar issue I was facing. I was trying to remove the event listener in the unrender method. This was much easier.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a Lightning issue its at the DOM level and would happen in any web tech.

The key here from the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

The bind() **method creates a new function** that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

This means in the addEventListener() call you are specifying a different function than in the removeEventListener() call - these must be exact refs to the same thing.

The .onmousemove= approach would only work if you switch away from addEventListener() for the wire up.

Comment: Good catch Doug. So what would be the best solution in that case? When I use addEventListener without bind I loose the component/helper reference (or is there a way back from a DOM event to the Lightning Component reference?)

Or do you know if I could use one of the base classes from the framework on the component level to react on mousemove events?

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to create a reference to the bound function like this:

```
this.boundMouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this);
```

and then use this reference for add / remove eventlistener

```
addEventListener('mousemove', this.boundMouseMove, false);
```

...

```
removeEventlistener('mousemove', this.boundMouseMove);
```

This got rid of the nasty 'self' variable

Answer (score 1):

This would usually occur if the signature for your add and remove event listeners aren't the same (that does not seem to be the case though). It's more of a workaround and not an ideal solution but you can nullify the `onmousemove` property

```
element.onmousemove = null; // Replace it with your exact element name
```

Alternatively, you can try with other mouse events such as `mouseover` and `mouseout` to see the behaviour. For reference, the list of events for a rich text area field for lightning component are listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputTextArea.htm).

Comment: Thank you Gaurav for your suggestion, but unfortunately this has no effect neither. When I output document.onmousemove directly after adding the listener the value is still null as well when I output it in the handler function. I have no idea why. Same with other mouse events.

Comment: Interesting, let me try it at my end to see what's going on